# I've been stuck with this error for like 2 weeks, I still haven't managed to fix it

Tags: discord.js

So I have updated my help command so that way the menu will be much cleaner and more up to date than my old one. However whenever I replace my old code with my new one I end up getting this Error and I can't seem to figure it out. I've tried commenting out different pieces of my command handler to see whether that fixes it but I had no luck. I've never had this before though. cmd.execute(bot, message, args) is only in the message.js event file apart from the handler. but even when I add that line of code into the file, it doesn't remove the error? it works fine on my old help code though. I also logged cmd in the command.js file in the handler after I defined cmd and it logs all the cmd info right above the error.

I have the cmd.execute(args, message, bot) that is being logged saying that I need it further down under where I define cmd in the help file, its the only file that is throwing the issue and it only happens if I use the new help.js menu.

**Error:**

```
TypeError: [ERROR][COMMANDS]: execute function is required for commands! (help.js)
    at /home/runner/RocketBot/utils/command.js:18:15
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (/home/runner/RocketBot/utils/command.js:8:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/RocketBot/index.js:19:30)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:132)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
```

**Files**

- Old Help Command: https://hasteb.in/tuhiduvi.js
- New Help Command: https://hasteb.in/awiyafap.js
- command.js: https://hasteb.in/ebuduyuv.js
- message.js: https://hasteb.in/oviwuvix.js

Comment: hi, perhaps step through with the debugger and see what `cmd` is when you log it?

Comment: that just logs whatever is in the `module.exports{}` for each command I have.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what the problem is, but I do see a line of code at the top of your new help command's execute method that makes no sense to me and could potentially cause problems: `cmd.execute(args, bot, message);`. Why is your help command attempting to execute the command specified in args[0]? Plus, the execution is incorrect, as it should be `(bot, message, args)`, not `(args, bot, message)`.

Comment: I didn't think that would affect anything, I did put args at the end instead but nothing changed in terms of the error. Could it have anything to do with the fact the line above it has `let cmd` and not `const cmd`? // edit: nah I just tried it, forget that.